# NASM linux X86 input parameters

Tags: assembly, nasm

I need to do an NASM linux X86 application that reads some input argument when is called from linux console, for example **./myapp arg1 arg2 arg3**. I already read and implemented [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285550-nasm-linux-getting-command-line-parameters/) example but when I execute the application and pass some arguments through console nothing happens, always go to **NoArgs** code block.

Heres my code:

```
VAR_MAX_ARGV equ 4;

sys_exit    equ     1
sys_read    equ     3
sys_write   equ     4
stdin       equ     0
stdout      equ     1
stderr      equ     3


SECTION .data  ;initialized data
szErrMsg    db      "Too many arguments.  The max number of args is 4", 10
ERRLEN      equ     $-szErrMsg
szLineFeed  db      10


SECTION .text   ;assembly code
extern printf

global _start
_start: 
    nop ;   
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ;push welcome_msg; 
    ;call printf

    cmp     dword [ebp + 4], 1
    je      NoArgs

    cmp     dword [ebp + 4], VAR_MAX_ARGV        ; check total args entered
    ja      TooManyArgs  

    ; push DWORD [i] DWORD directiva de tamanio de memoria
    jmp     finish


NoArgs:
   ; No args entered,
   ; start program without args here
    jmp     finish


TooManyArgs:
    mov     eax, sys_write
    mov     ebx, stdout
    mov     ecx, szErrMsg
    mov     edx, ERRLEN
    int     80H

finish:
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp

    mov     eax, sys_exit
    xor     ebx, ebx
    int     80H

SECTION .bss ;unitialized data
```

What can be wrong?

PD: The application is running on Ubuntu 14.04 X86 on a Intel Core i7

Comment: Can you give me the command line that you execute? which O.S are you running?

Comment: debian stable. I did: `nasm -f elf32 test.asm && gcc -m32 -nostdlib test.o && ./a.out 1 2 3 4` and got the "too many arguments" printed.

Comment: Please try with less dan 3 arguments on console. I just try it and the problem continues

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, with less than 3 arguments you jump to `finish` and that just exits the program.